# Ultra dark mode is only applied to the options menu and does not persist through page loads

Tags: bug, status-completed, april-fools, dark-mode

I'm not sure if this is intended, but Ultra Dark Mode (the April Fool's joke) only remains activated on the preferences page and does not persist through page loads. If I refresh the page or if I click on the Stack Overflow logo, it doesn't persist.

Comment: The persistence was working yesterday. I remember because in Chrome your cursor is a flashlight and it worked in the Suggested Edits queue. However, I'm having the same issue. Might be on purpose since April Fool's is over.

Comment: I'm sure it's intended. I'm never again refreshing the homepage that I loaded yesterday! :)

Comment: @BSMP I don't know if it's done like that on purpose, because the "feature" is supposed to last until the 5th of April.

Comment: @BSMP The ultra post illustration with its light circle looked like maybe the cursor was a flashlight but I couldn't get such a circle effect. So, glad to hear that was the case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I, uh... well. ‍♂️

Spot the problem:

[image]

We extended the run time for ultra dark mode at last minute and I sort of forgot I did that. Time is an illusion.

Comment: You could also consider changing the second and forth digit to 1's :)

Comment: What if you "*accidentally*" set the year to `Infinity`.

Comment: @Zera I'm afraid `new DateTime(Infinity, 4, 3)` doesn't compile :(

Comment: PLZ bring back Ultra Dark Mode? Is there some sort of extension in Stack Apps that will help bring it back?

Comment: @zixuan Not that I'm aware of, I'm sorry. The "ultra" dark mode wasn't designed to be actually usable and we never intended to support it in production as it was initially deployed. As we get closer to a full release of the dark mode beta, though, I believe there are some plans to explore higher contrast options as well.